# How can I map html data to d3?

Tags: d3.js

In d3.js I often have data like the following:

```
 nodes = [
    {x: 30, y: 50},
    {x: 50, y: 80},
    {x: 90, y: 120}
  ]
```

Now I'd like to get my data out of a div tag (not instantiating it inside the js / coffee)
The html code could look like this:

```
<div id="nodes">
  <div class="node" data-x="30" data-y="50"></div>
  <div class="node" data-x="50" data-y="80"></div>
  <div class="node" data-x="90" data-y="120"></div>
</div>
```

I'm looking for something like the following (but actually working of course):

```
  nodes = d3.selectAll(".node")
```

Changing the format of my html would be no problem. I want to avoid working with **external** json files though.

Comment: You would need to do something like `var data = []; d3.selectAll(".node").each(function() { data.push([d3.select(this).attr("data-x"), d3.select(this).attr("data-y")]); })`.

Comment: Thank you, that would in fact make it possible. It does not seem very elegant though. (I have to name the data-xyz in the js again and the code gets bigger for every attribute I add.) Am I doing something fundamentally wrong for even trying this? In my eyes this should be a standard use case of d3.js.

Comment: The standard case is that you get your data from some external resource (or even hardcoded into the JS), not as attributes in individual elements. I would stick with this if at all possible.

Comment: Okay, I will be using json then. Ty for your help @LarsKotthoff.

Comment: Seems like a good job for jQuery. .each is generally fairly costly as a calculation. So try and use another way if you can.

Comment: Have look here on jQuery's .each vs. a for loop: http://jsperf.com/jquery-each-vs-for-loop/11 I would use a for loop to create an array with your values. Then I'd use those as your data. Unless you plan on having more than 50 or so elements, you can save some cost from not making the json call.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With your help I ended up with the following:
(rails-)html to transfer the data to the user:

```
<%= content_tag "div", class: "graph", data: { nodes: @nodes, links: @links} do %>
```

coffeescript with jquery to access the data:

```
nodesD = $('.graph').data('nodes')
```

rails controller to create the data:

```
@neo_servers.each do |neo|
      @nodes << {x: x, y: y, name: neo['server']['data']['name']}
      x += 10; y += 2
end
```

which in the end returns a nice graph :)

As proposed, I used jquery and d3 where they are strong. jquery to get the data, d3 to modify and visualize it.

Hope this helps someone in the future.

[image]